# Is it possible to check the Solana program `macro` correctness before deployment?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana, solana-program-library

When we want to deploy program to Solana, first we need to generate the program keypair and insert the public key in my `declare_id!` macro in lib.rs.

for example:

```
use anchor_lang::{prelude::*, solana_program::pubkey};

// this one
declare_id!("3qoBD26MJXRaCqgURhcRP2sz1U9pNoskVjLwzx62S5KE");

#[program]
mod anchor_example {
    use anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction;

    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64, authority: Pubkey) -> Result<()> { 
....
```

Because I want to expose an API interface for user to upload their `.so` file & specify the expected program ID, and I'll do the uploading for them(I'll manage their keypair btw).

Just wondering if it is possible to detect if the pubkey inside `declare_id!` is equal to the expected program ID input by user before actual deployment?

So that I can tell the user that he is inserting the wrong pubkey inside his solana program.

Thanks